# Why is this Zend framework killing my CPU usage and loading pages so slow

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, social-networking, socialengine

The framework I am using is called SocialEngine.net v4, and it's completely written in Zend, so it's insanely super CPU intensive. SocialEngine is in PHP and uses MySQL.

I need to know what OS, what hardware you suggest (dual xeons, amd, how much ram, etc...) and how to optimize it properly to handle large amounts of traffic.

I only have 11k users right now, and it's running incredibly slow, I'm talking 7 second page load times.

The framework however does have memcached, and apc options for caching installed, but even with APC or Memcache on, it doesn't make a big enough difference...

I need to know what the best way to attack this is as far as optimizing mysql, inoodb tweaks, apache tweaks, any performance tweaks, what type of hardware, and amount of ram.

I have a very big marketing plan in place, and will probably start increasing traffic by 1,000+ signups per day... So traffic will start to rise very progressively. When I initially marketed, I did 50k uniques in 6 hours, 20k signups, and 500k pageviews... (server crashed, lost half my users... and haven't marketed since, because I been trying to rebuild)

Comment: are you able to make application-level changes or purely server-level changes?

Answer (score 6):

You could start with [xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) to profile your application and find the bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

Honestly? And this is just my opinion, instead of spending a small fortune on a single server - buy many small servers and load balance them.  Mac Mini's are wonderful for this and are capable of running their standard OS X or Linux if you choose.  You will get way more performance out of 10 small $500 machines than you will out of 1 $5000 machine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide us with any information about your set up.

How many servers do you have? What services are they running?

When you say APC and Memcached is on, have you actually set them up to actually work?

How many connections does your Apache allow for?

What is your MySQL configuration like? Is the memory settings optimised? Most importantly are all your tables indexed properly? Have you checked your slow query log? Did you run EXPLAIN for your queries?

ZF wise, are you caching your table metadata? Are you caching tables that don't change so that you save network traffic? Have you checked the official ZF optimisation guide?

Also... Why did you assume that ZF is killing your CPU usage?

Comment: See that's the kind of stuff I am looking for :) Thank you, I will look into all of this asap.

Comment: I just don't know how to optimize mysql, apache, or what the settings should be.